# How can I download Wordpress on my server automatically?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to provide my Wordpress Theme for users to download. I thought it would be nice to give them also an option to download the newest version of Wordpress which includes my theme. The URL of the newst version of Wordpress is: https://wordpress.org/latest.zip

I would like to do the following:

1. First download the latest version of Wordpress on the server
2. Unzip it (if needed)
3. Move my theme to the theme directory
4. Zip it back (if needed)
5. Provide it to download

Once the zip file is on my FTP server, I don't see any problems to move or unzip files. The question is rather: How can I download Wordpress on my server?

Comment: This question will most likely be closed as it does not come within the scope of the site as can be seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you have a particular programming issue, then please update your question to include your code attempt and your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are using an apache/linux server us this CLI command on $

```
wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
```

this will download the latest wordpress release into your user folder on your server. From there you can unpack and move it to var/www/...

Comment: That means every time there is a new version, I have to use the same command to download the newest one? Wouldn't there be a way to download the zip file for every time the user sends a request?

Comment: No, once you installed WP, you won't have to repeat the same process for every update. It will update itself automatically.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: the wordpress link always contains the latest stable release. If you have already a WP installation runing, you get informed about possible updates in the wp-admin section. There are plugins which trigger autoupdates but if you have some customization (custom fields etc). and own code which effects the core, you should be careful. Data might be lost. I would never recommend to update automatically, for minor release updates like from 4.3.2. to 4.3.5. I would only do in case of security updates.